# Correct way to install Ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Currently I am trying to install Ipython notebook on my mac (OS 10) with command

`pip3 install ipython[all]` and `pip3 install ipython[notebook]`.

I checked most resources online and followed the introduction; all dependencies were installed, but I still can't start it. The issue is when I type command

`iptest`

in terminal, it returns

`-bash: iptest: command not found`.

When I type command

`ipython notebook`, it returns

`/usr/bin/python: No module named iPython`.

Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. In general, the way to install the notebook for Python 3 would be:

```
pip3 install notebook
```

which you would launch with

```
jupyter notebook
```

On OS X, you have to be careful, because where Python puts executables (`ipython`, `jupyter`, etc.) can vary, and in some common cases is not on your default PATH.

If you got Python from Python.org, then executables will be installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
```

(3.5 assumes you have Python 3.5, it could be 2.7, 3.4, etc.)

You can add this to your PATH in ~/.bashrc with:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:$PATH
```

This error:

> ```
> $ ipython notebook
> /usr/bin/python: No module named IPython
> ```

suggests that you used to have IPython installed for System Python, but no longer have it, and whatever removed the install left the executable lying around, though. If this is the case, you may want to remove the broken ipython executable. You can see where it might be with:

```
which -a ipython
```

and then remove the erroneous file, such as:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply. After I follow you instruction, there are still problems. First I use version 3.4 and I find excitable file in the `bin` file, named as jupyter-notebook. Jupyter notebook runs well after I click it. But I can't do it in terminal. Even after add Path. Also the remove commend doesn't work, with return `No such file or directory `. That's really wired.

Comment: What are `which jupyter` and `which jupyter-notebook` and `$PATH`?

Comment: thanks again! After checking, I found the problem was my bash_profile and I delete bashrc file. It worked after I create that file and add source in bash_profile.